# RetroPie won’t start up after I manually shut it down

Tags: boot

[image]
I just setup my RetroPie and tested out a game. I then shut it off using the power button. When I tried starting it up again it doesn’t go past this screen. I unplugged it for an hour and tried again but no luck. How can I get it to work again?

Comment: You should always shutdown your Pi not just turn the power off.

Comment: set up the RetroPie again

Comment: What power button? One that was set up as a shutdown/startup button? Or something else?

Answer (score 0):

I think there was an issue with my sad card. Tried another one and had no issues.

Comment: Try reflashing your sad card.

Comment: I don't believe it's a problem with the SD Card. You should never just power off the RasPi. That may result in a kernel corruption as you see because it has no chance to close its open files. Always do a proper shutdown of the operating system by calling its poweroff functions before switching off the power.

Comment: Please accept your own answer with a click on the tick on its left side. Only this will finish the question and it will not pop up again year for year.

Answer (score -1):

You have a kernel panic, which means that the kernel encounters something unrecoverable so it stops there and stay there.

You can turn it off at such a kernel
Panic and turn it on again after a few seconds. If nothing is corrupted it should come up properly. If not, try another SD-card.

Comment: Downvoted?  Care to say why?

Comment: You have to ask the "downvoter" but he doesn't see your comment. You have to address him with @downvoter. You see the problem to get an answer?